# How do i find the right most digit of a number integer with java without using number % 10? see the description

Tags: java, printf, modulus

Right now I'm using something like this:
Basically the program is supposed to
print X (right most digit of a #) to X decimal places for example:

- entered 3.56, should  display 0000000000000003.560
- entered 56.7 should display: 000000000056.700000
- entering 1002.5 should display 00000000000001002.50

but number `% 10`,condition right now only accepts number 
w/o decimals, so the program closes if i enter
a number with decimals
I only need an alternative for number `% 10`.

```
double number;
if (number % 10 == 1)
System.out.printf("%020.1f\n",number);
```

Comment: I don't understand what it is supposed to do. Printing a digit to that number of decimal places makes no sense, and doesn't match your examples. I don't think you are using the words correctly.

Comment: Your title says "the right most digit of an integer", but `number` is a `double`.  What exactly do you need?

Comment: I "see the description".  I still have no clue what it means.

Comment: Why in the world would you want those outputs in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I was having difficulty being able to post part the code.

Comment: What do `000000000056.7000000` and `0000000000000003.560 ` have in common in relation to `3.56` and `56.7`? I don't see it.

Comment: I need the outputs for a project, my only problem is finding an alternative to (number % 10).

Comment: ok so you see 56.7 (6 is the right most digit integer in the number) so 000000000056.700000 <- has 6 decimal places. With a field width of 20. in (3.56) 3 is the right most integer digit, so 0000000000000003.560 <- has 3 decimal places

Comment: Why do you want to not use `%`?  Is it forbidden to use this, or is it just not working the way you want?  If it's the second one, try saying `(int)number % 10`, to convert the double to an integer (and throw away all the digits to the right of the decimal).

Comment: yes, now i need to find another way besides (number % 10); because my program only displays numbers w/o decimals.

Comment: I need the numbers after the decimals

Comment: You'd store the result of `(int)number % 10` in a separate variable to determine the number of decimal places you need, and use that variable in your `printf` statement.

Comment: another example is if someone entered: 1034545.2132 it should display 00000001034545.21320              ex2. if entered 10568.25 it should display 00000010568.25000000

Comment: If this is a response to me, "throw away the digits to the right of the decimal" doesn't mean throw them away permanently.  `(int)number` will return `number` with all the digits to the right of the decimal thrown away, but this won't change the value of `number` unless you assign `number = (int)number` or something.

Comment: In your previous code example you ware using `%10` but in title you are saying `without using number % 10`. So can you use `%10` or not?

Comment: @Brian DO, What do you want this condition to check for `if (number % 10 == 1)`.  It is unclear your intention.

Comment: `"another example is if someone entered: 1034545.2132 it should display 00000001034545.21320 ex2. if entered 10568.25 it should display 00000010568.25000000"`.  This still makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: basically (number % 10 == 1) means, if the right most integer digit of a number is 1 make the output display only 1 decimal place example= 341.3332444 it should display 341.3

Comment: if the right most integer digit of a number is 4 (number %10) make the output display 4 decimal places    example entered: 5674.3443122123 it should display only 5674.3443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something like

```
System.out.printf("%020." + ((int) number) % 10 + "f\n", number);
```

`((int) number)` will get rid of fraction making `56.7` -> `56`, so now you can safely use `%10` to get last digit.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/K9TU1o)

Answer (score 1):

If I have interpreted your question correctly then this looks like it does what you ask:

```
public void test() {
  strangePrint(3.1415);
  strangePrint(2.0);
  strangePrint(2.1);
  strangePrint(2.2);
  strangePrint(2.999);
  strangePrint(37.4);
  strangePrint(3.56);
  strangePrint(56.7);
  strangePrint(1002.5);
}

private void strangePrint(double d) {
  // Get the integer part
  int n = (int)d;
  // The last digit of the integer defines the decimal places.
  int digits = n%10;
  System.out.printf("%020."+digits+"f\n", d);
}
```

prints

```
0000000000000003.142
00000000000000002.00
00000000000000002.10
00000000000000002.20
00000000000000003.00
000000000037.4000000
0000000000000003.560
0000000000056.700000
00000000000001002.50
```

Comment: @BrianDo I thought you said you couldn't use the mod operator.  If that's still the case, my solution works.

Comment: I can use it, but i thought there was another way let me try it

Answer (score 0):

From number in format:

```
ABCDEX.FGHI
```

you can extract X by:

```
int x = (int) original; //get rid of what is after the decimal point
//now x is ABCDEX
x = x % 10;
//now x is X
```

now you can join this int with string to create pattern for printf.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your original post, it seemed like you weren't allowed to use mod, so here's how I would do it:

```
private void transform(Double number)
{
    int result;
    int x = number.intValue();

    if (x < 10)
    {
        result = x;
    }
    else
    {
        Double y = x / 10.0;
        int z = y.intValue();
        result = x-10*z;
    }

    System.out.printf("%020." + result + "f\n", number);
}
```

Test runs:

```
transform(3.56);
transform(56.7);
transform(1002.5);
```

Prints:

> 0000000000000003.560
>   0000000000056.700000
>   00000000000001002.50

**EDIT:**
If I misinterpreted and you are allowed to use mod, then the answer is simply:

```
private void transform(Double number)
{ 
     System.out.printf("%020." + ((int) number) % 10 + "f\n", number);
}
```

as others have suggested.  Sorry if I misunderstood.