# Why do so many of the Java libraries take `String` where `CharSequence` would do?

Tags: java, string, charsequence

I was frustrated recently in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737368/823393) question where OP wanted to change the format of the output depending on a feature of the number being formatted.

The natural mechanism would be to construct the format dynamically but because `PrintStream.format` takes a `String` instead of a `CharSequence` the construction must end in the construction of a `String`.

It would have been so much more natural and efficient to build a class that implemented `CharSequence` that provided the dynamic format on the fly without having to create yet another `String`.

This seems to be a common theme in the Java libraries where the default seems to be to require a `String` even though immutability is not a requirement. I am aware that keys in `Map`s and `Set`s should generally be immutable for obvious reasons but as far as I can see `String` is used far too often where a `CharSequence` would suffice.

Comment: And the question to answer is? This seems like a question which should be directed at the developers.

Comment: @Patrick - Is there a good reason for using `String` so much that I have missed?

Comment: The @since items tell you all you need to answer this question.

Comment: @EJP - In the case of `PrintStream.format` it is a 1.5 feature - `CharSequence` has been available since 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons.

- In a lot of cases, immutability is a functional requirement.  For example, you've identified that a lot of collections / collection types will "break" if an element or key is mutated.
- In a lot of cases, immutability is a security requirement.  For instance, in an environment where you are running untrusted code in a sandbox, any case where untrusted code could pass a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` to trusted code is a potential security problem<sup>1</sup>.
- In a lot of cases, the reason is backwards compatibility.  The `CharSequence` interface was introduced in Java 1.4.  Java APIs that predate Java 1.4 do not use it.  Furthermore, changing an preexisting method that uses `String` to use `CharSequence` risks binary compatibility issues; i.e. it could prevent old Java code from running on a newer JVM.
- In the remainder it could simply be - "too much work, too little time".  Making changes to existing standard APIs involves a lot of effort to make sure that the change is going to be acceptable to everyone (e.g. checking for the above), and *convincing* everyone that it will all be OK.  Work has to be prioritized.

So while you find this frustrating, it is unavoidable.

---

<sup>1 - This would leave the Java API designer with an awkward choice.  Does he/she write the API to make (expensive) defensive copies whenever it is passed a mutable "string", and possibly change the semantics of the API (from the user's perspective!).  Or does he/she label the API as "unsafe for untrusted code" ... and hope that developers notice / understand?</sup>

<sup>Of course, when you are designing your own APIs for your own reasons, you can make the call that security is not an issue.  The Java API designers are not in that position.  They need to design APIs that work for everyone.  Using `String` is the simplest / least risky solution.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Do you notice the part that explains that it has been around since 1.4? Previously all the API methods used `String` (which has been around since 1.0)

Comment: But `PrintStream.format(String format,Object... args)` was added in 1.5 long after `CharSequence` was available - and yet still they chose `String`. What am I missing?

Comment: Not to have to reimplement the iteration over the String? notice that with `CharSequence` methods, you either do that or call `toString()`

Comment: Iterating across a `CharSequence` is exactly the same effort as iterating across a `String` - or am I missing something?